# What is a "driver information database" in Windows 9x?

Tags: windows-98, driver, windows-me

At first boot post-installation or when installing third-party device drivers in Windows 95/98/ME, it's common to see the following dialog:

[image: A screenshot of Windows 98 showing an active window without any buttons, entitled “Building driver information database”, with text inside “Please wait while Windows builds a driver information database.” and a progress bar at 70%. Behind it there is a notification window informing of new hardware being detected.]

So what is this "driver information database" which doesn't appear in the NT lineage? Where is this database, and what is stored in it? What's its significance in the Windows 9x driver model?